# Cannot delete a comment from a deleted answer - no error, no activity?

Tags: bug, status-completed, comments, deleted-answers

Sorry if this has already been discussed, but I've searched first and can't find any information about it.

I asked a question over on SO, and [one of the answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4186172/is-there-any-way-to-clean-up-the-following-generic-method-using-any-of-the-new-c/4186257#4186257) was deleted. I then figured I'd just delete the comment I made on that answer (as I sound a little dumb), however nothing happens:

- I click delete
- Click OK on when asked if I'm sure
  I'd *really* like to delete the
  comment
- Then it appears to do an AJAX call,
  but then nothing else happens.

This is using FF, but the same nothingness happens on IE as well.

Comment: My magic 8 ball says this won't get fixed, but I agree it should work.

Comment: I was going to say that it works for me, but then it turns out that I can also upvote comments on deleted posts. So never mind.

Comment: I was about to mention that if you really wanted to, you could flag a moderator down since they don't concern themselves with limits on deleted questions... but...

Comment: I think this should work. Or the delete button shouldn't be there, or at the very least it should give some user feedback as to why it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are now able to delete your comments on a deleted post, provided you have [enough rep](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/privileges/moderator-tools) to see the deleted post.

This fix will be deployed tonight.